# Mockito doAnswer & thenReturn in one method

Tags: java, mockito

I have a situation where my method is returning some object, and method is containing some arguments and I have condition on the basis of returned response and one of the argument.

```
Map<String,List<Object>> testMap = new HashMap<>(); 
Object obj = new Object(); 

Set<String> test = myService.getModelSearchStrings(testMap, obj);
if(CollectionUtils.isNotEmpty(test){

}

if(MapUtils.isNotEmpty(testMap){

}
```

Test:

```
Set<String> result = new HashSet<>();
result.add("123");

Mockito.when(mockedMtnService.getModelSearchStrings(Mockito.anyMap(), Mockito.anyObject())).thenReturn(result);
```

I want to return Dummy response i.e. result HashSet and want to update argument value(Map).

Comment: I'm not quite sure about the question, the code looks okay. Maybe you should post a complete example (code and test) and the error message or expected/unexpected behaviour.

Answer (score 18):

I can only assume that you are looking for `thenAnswer` & [Answer](http://static.javadoc.io/org.mockito/mockito-core/2.2.11/org/mockito/stubbing/Answer.html). With `thenAnswer` you can modify the arguments of the mocked method and also return a result from that method.

E.g:

```
Set<String> result = new HashSet<>();
result.add("123");

Mockito.when(mockedMtnService.getModelSearchStrings(Mockito.anyMap(), Mockito.anyObject())).thenAnswer(new Answer<Set>() {
    @Override
    public String answer(InvocationOnMock invocation) throws Throwable {
        Map<String,List<Object>> mapArg = (Map<String,List<Object>>)invocation.getArguments()[0];
        // do something with mapArg....
        return result;
    }
});
```

Or with Java 8 lambda:

```
Mockito.when(mockedMtnService.getModelSearchStrings(Mockito.anyMap(), Mockito.anyObject())).thenAnswer(invocation -> {
    Map<String,List<Object>> mapArg = (Map<String,List<Object>>)invocation.getArguments()[0];
    // do something with mapArg....
    return result;
});
```

Comment: Totally unrelated: I saw that your flagged for "editing" on the triage queue for https://stackoverflow.com/review/triage/20799771 ... simply: wrong decision. This question requires the OP to remove the screen shots, and to put the corresponding text into the question as text. Only the OP should do such things. So please keep in mind: only triage for editing when *other* people can edit the question. Anything that requires the *owner* to improve the content, should not go "edit".

Comment: Similar for https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52234471/how-to-calculate-the-radius-of-different-locations-locations-lat-and-long-are ... there is NOTHING that anybody else besides the OP can do to improve this question. So, seriously: be much more cautious about triaging to "edit".

Comment: Wow this made my day, thanks! Sometimes it's hard to make tests for convoluted and poorly coded methods